# How can I get my shadow around my entire div?

Tags: html, css

For my site I want to show some products on my site and when you hover over these products, there should be more information. Currently the design for the product card is there. I have 2 questions that I cannot get to work.

1. I cannot get the shadow box around the whole div when I hover around it. Have tried to add a height to my div but that messed up the layout of my other divs. What am I doing wrong?
2. Also the border of my div  goes through my button (at least the link I have styled as a button). How can I fix this?

```css
.home-products {
  width: auto;
  height: 250px;
}

.product-image-home {
  height: 200px;
}

.product-grid {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 225px;
}

.product-grid h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.product-overlay-button {
  background: #85bf31;
  height: 550px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-grid:hover {}

.product-info {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 225px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.product-info p {
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.product-grid:hover .product-info {
  display: block;
}

.product-grid:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-products">
  <div class="product-grid">
    <img class="product-image-home" src="https://cardpile.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/blood-rage-460x460.jpg" alt="Homepage">
    <h3>Bloodrage</h3>
    <span>€38.90</span>
    <div class="product-info">
      <p>Some information about the product!</p>
      <a href="www.mysite.com" class="product-overlay-button">Vergelijk prijzen</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of your issues come from `.product-info` having `position: absolute;`. So remove that (both of them, you have `position: absolute;` in there twice); then you can add some `padding-bottom` to `.product-grid` to "fit" your button inside the `div`.

Check out what I did here:

```css
.home-products {
  width: auto;
  height: 250px;
}

.product-image-home {
  height: 200px;
}

.product-grid {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 225px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.product-grid h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.product-overlay-button {
  background: #85bf31;
  height: 550px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-grid:hover {}

.product-info {
  display: none;
  width: 225px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.product-info p {
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.product-grid:hover .product-info {
  display: block;
}

.product-grid:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-products">
  <div class="product-grid">
    <img class="product-image-home" src="https://cardpile.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/blood-rage-460x460.jpg" alt="Homepage">
    <h3>Bloodrage</h3>
    <span>€38.90</span>
    <div class="product-info">
      <p>Some information about the product</p>
      <a href="www.mysite.com" class="product-overlay-button">Vergelijk prijzen</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi John, your suggestion works for the shadow so thanks for that. Only problem is that when you put a text or something under it the layout changes. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you explain further? for instance put text under what and where? and how does it change? If you can provide code where the issue occurs that'd be helpful.

Comment: Sure makes sense, so what I am trying to do is set multiple of these products on the home page. Then under the products I want to have other product or some text but the layout changes. There is an example in this pen: https://codepen.io/PHV/pen/vYxxQQY?editors=1100

Comment: sure this can be solved my making `.product-grid` have `position: absolute;`   `background-color: white;` and  `z-index: 1;` See here: https://jsfiddle.net/whLo70ef/2/

Comment: Damn hero! Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use shadow settings similar to `0px 0px 10px 4px` (i.e. the first *and* second values are zero, so the shadow will be spread equally on all sides according to the third and fourth values):

```css
.home-products {
  width: auto;
  height: 250px;
}

.product-image-home {
  height: 200px;
}

.product-grid {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 225px;
}

.product-grid h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.product-overlay-button {
  background: #85bf31;
  height: 550px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-grid:hover {}

.product-info {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 225px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.product-info p {
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.product-grid:hover .product-info {
  display: block;
}

.product-grid:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-products">
  <div class="product-grid">
    <img class="product-image-home" src="https://cardpile.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/blood-rage-460x460.jpg" alt="Homepage">
    <h3>Bloodrage</h3>
    <span>€38.90</span>
    <div class="product-info">
      <p>Some information about the product!</p>
      <a href="www.mysite.com" class="product-overlay-button">Vergelijk prijzen</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```